# Formatting data in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a field which is a Double. For display on a the report, if that value is negative, then I need to reverse the number by multiplying it by -1. The result should be formatted like this: "(1,000)" (notice no "-" sign). How can I do this in Crystal? I was using a Display String formula to try to do this since the "Reverse sign for display" option doesn't work for me (because it needs to be a formula for other reasons).

So far I have:

```
if {columnName} < 0 then
  "(" & ToText({columnName}, "#,###", 0) & ")"
else
  "(" & ToText({columnName} * -1, "#,###", 0) & ")"
```

But this gives me something like this: "(-6,500)", and I need to get rid of that pesky minus sign.

**Edit:**
I implemented a formula field like this:

```
-Abs({columnName})
```

Then selected the format that looks like (1,234) from the format list as Craig answered below.

Comment: You have your if condition round the wrong way do you not?

Comment: I always want it to appear negative. It's like reverse absolute value.

Comment: @Brandon Montgomery: Yes, but you are performing the ` \* -1` on the wrong part.

Comment: I keep looking at it, and I don't think so. If the value is already negative, I'm leaving it alone, else, I'm inverting it.

Comment: @Brandon Montgomery: You want to do the exact opposite.  You need to make negatives positive for the `ToText()` routine to return an unsigned number and leave positives alone.

Comment: oooooohhhhhhhhh I feel like an idiot. Gotcha.

Comment: @Brandon Montgomery: Shouldn't worry.  Condition reversals are amongst the most common of logic errors, and amongst the hardest to notice.  I've had persistent errors that have taken me hours to find because of those before now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crystal Reports supports 'accounting' formatting w/o much effort:

- right click field, select Format Field...
- select Number tab (if not selected)
- choose the style that resembles '(1,123.00)'

** edit **

You can also apply this formatting to a formula field.

Comment: exactly what I was writting... you beat me too it

Comment: OK, but I also need to invert the value that comes in before it does its accounting style formatting. How would I make sure the value is negative?

Comment: so, negative values need to be positive and positive value need to be negative?  if so, create a formula to multiple the original value by -1, then apply the formatting i describe to the formula field.

Answer (score 1):

I have accomplished my requirement this way< I have added a formula and assigned sum of the required field then I set its Format (12,34.00) also i have removed Dollar sign.

```
Formula = replace(totext(Sum({myfield}) * -1),"$","")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have face same pro blame but it OS specific . ON windows xp no any formatting problem  but above xp this issue face. Use following formula in Display Formula after removing all formatting .

Replace(Replace(Replace(ToText (CurrentFieldValue, "##,##,##,##0.00", 2),"$",""),"-",""),",","")